# XPath in MSBuild (SDC) and WIX

Tags: msbuild, xpath, wix, microsoft.sdc.tasks

Fresh Asking of this Question->

I have a WIX file that I need to modify using MSBuild.  It starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">

  <?--... Various Removed Params ...-->

  <Product Id='$(var.ProductCode)'
    UpgradeCode='$(var.UpgradeCode)'
    Name='$(var.AppName)' Language="1033" Version='$(var.ProductVersion)'
    Manufacturer='$(var.Manufacturer)'>
    <Package Id='$(var.PackageCode)' InstallerVersion="200" 
    Compressed="yes" />

  <?--... More of the WIX XML file ...-->

  <iis:WebApplication Id='STWebApp' Name='MyWebSite' Isolation='medium' />

  <?--... Rest of the WIX XML file ...-->
```

My problem is the SDC tasks can't seem to reference any of the xml nodes that are WIX related.  For example:

```
<XmlFile.SetAttribute Path="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\TestProduct.wxs"
         XPath="//iis:WebApplication" Namespaces="@(Namespaces)" 
         Name="Name" Value="$(VersionTag)"/>
```

works just fine because it does not use any Wix nodes (just an iis one), but if I use the full XPath path to it (*/Wix/Product/iis:WebApplication*) the task returns:
    **Could not find resource string No matches found for XPath expression**

This is not a problem till I want to reference a Directory node (/Wix/Product/Directory/Directory/Directory/Directory[@Id='STWebSiteDir'])

I have tried using the full XPath and the shorter //Directory[@Id='STWebSiteDir'].  I have tried single quotes and double quotes, **I have tried adding the WIX namespace to the call (with no prefix).**

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Namespaces Include="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
    <Prefix>iis</Prefix>
    <Uri>http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension</Uri>
  </Namespaces>
  <Namespaces Include="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Prefix></Prefix>
    <Uri>http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi</Uri>
  </Namespaces>
</ItemGroup>
```

I have even tried to just get a reference to /Wix/Product and even that fails:

```
<XmlFile.SetAttribute Path="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\TestProduct.wxs" 
            XPath="/Wix/Product" Namespaces="@(Namespaces)" 
            Name="Name" Value="MODIFIED"/>
```

I am clearly missing something.  Anyone with a hint on where to go to get this to work?

Vaccano

Comment: If your XPath engine is standar complain, this is FAQ: a QName test without prefix selects elements in the null (or empty) namespace URI, not in the default namespace. So, you need to register the namespace URI and prefix binding and add this prefix to your path, i.e.: `/wi:Wix/wi:Product`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just define the variables on the command line to the preprocessor?

```
candle -dVariableName=ValueForVariable
```

That might be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the Wix default namespace in @(Namespaces)?

Comment: I must not understand you because I have the WIx namepace there in my question!!!!!

Comment: So the solution you have below is what I was attempting to say.  Default is different to Empty.

Comment: True enough.  Voted you up instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Namespaces Include="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
    <Prefix>iis</Prefix>
    <Uri>http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension</Uri>
  </Namespaces>
  <Namespaces Include="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
     <Prefix>wis</Prefix>
    <Uri>http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi</Uri>
  </Namespaces>
</ItemGroup>
```

you should add a prefix for wi namespace too,after that it can ok,i have test it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is the answer:

The namespace prefix needed to be missing for the wix part, not just left empty

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Namespaces Include="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
    <Prefix>iis</Prefix>
    <Uri>http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension</Uri>
  </Namespaces>
  <Namespaces Include="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <Uri>http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi</Uri>
  </Namespaces>
</ItemGroup>
```

And then you need to add a prefix value to the wix namespace in the file.  I used tst.

Vaccano